# How many people can play multiplayer factorio together?

Tags: factorio

I played factorio with friends yesterday, we were able to play with 5 people together in the same map very consistently, but the sixth player kept timeouting and making the other players lag.

We're blaming player 6's computer for now, and are hyped for what looks like a 8+ player game this weekend.

It that even possible? Is there a hard limit on the number of players? I couldn't find one. We're not really worried on the server's side, it has plenty of resources and bandwidth, but we wonder if maybe the game doesn't support 6+ players together.

Comment: A stream on 9PM GMT, 2016-09-20, players are trying to stress test the player limits. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mscfPJ7czFE

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The hard limit is currently 255. We never tested it for more than 12 people on local network so different kind of problems might arise when lot of people play.

Edit:
Since 0.14 the limit has been increased to 65535 and it might actually be possible to get that number of players online with exceptionally good network connection.

Comment: Interesting, are you one of the staff ? Last answer referred to a forum answer from a staff member, but the post is from 2013. Did the number change since then? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm the founder of Factorio and lead programmer :) On some places it might look like 65535 is the limit, but it actually is 255. Increasing it wouldn't be a hard thing to do, but as I said earlier, the bottleneck would be different things anyway.

Comment: @Marwin Oh! It's you that ruined my life... Just kidding, I love the game. Great job!!

Answer (score 9):

The hard limit for number of players playing together is [65535.](https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=6481&p=50661#p50586)

Because it is in early access, some content may be buggy, so we cannot say for sure exactly how many players will be able to play together (this should also increase over time).

Comment: Thank you! We were able to play with 7 players with no lag, the 8th one had issues and went to play another game.

Answer (score 1):

0.14 update massively improved multiplayer. On experimental branch there was several multiplayer games with 150-200 players.

You can watch streams of it on youtube playlist:
[Factorio Mass Multiplayer](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLH-huzMEgGWBEUzvuHes3fKA1Ut-nKqCy)